# Is there a way to get a list of nodes belonging to a role

Tags: chef-infra

Is there a way to get a list of nodes (and their IPs for example) that have been assigned to a role?

Comment: Are you using Chef Server? More information is needed.

Comment: Agree with @sethvargo. You have this tagged as chef-recipe; do you want to see all nodes for a role inside a recipe? If so, what do you want that recipe to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by sethvargo, if you are using Chef Server you could use the knife search in your terminal

```
$ knife search 'role:myrolename'
```

Answer (score 0):

Chef allows you to search all nodes that have a role. Example below

```
search(:node, 'role:myrole').each do |all_nodes_with_myrole|
  # code here
end
```